# Are bash error traps guaranteed to NOT make recursive calls?

Tags: bash, recursion, error-handling, runtime-error

Bash traps seem to automatically avoid recursion. In this example, I expected infinite recursion because I couldn't find documentation explicitly prohibiting it; but, the output stops.

I'm probably missing something obvious but I can't find documentation that guarantees non-recursion in the man page. Can anyone find official documentation discussing this?

```
    #!/bin/bash
    set -Eu
    err1()
    {
        echo in err1
        false
    }
    err2()
    {
        echo in err2
        false
    }

    trap 'err1 ; err2' ERR

    false
```

Ouptput is:

```
    in err1
    in err2
```

Comment: use `set -vx` to see the debug/trace flow? Sorry, not a documentation wonk ;-) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The ERR trap is not inherited by subshells (including function calls) unless you `set -o errtrace`. That would automatically include trap handlers.

Even if you do set the shell option, the ERR trap won't be called inside a trap handler, afaik. The bash manual does not appear to mention this.